# Como mostrar el contenido de mi base de datos en un documento con php

Tags: php

Que tal gente tengo una base de datos con un formulario muy sencillo y solo quiero mostrar la información de la base en una tablita algo sencillo.

Este es el código php.

> ```
> <?php
> $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','tienda')
> or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
>
> insertar($conexion);
> function insertar ($conexion){
> $cedula=$_POST['cedula'];
> $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
> $correo=$_POST['correo'];
> $fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
> $direccion=$_POST['direccion'];
>
>
> $consulta = "INSERT INTO cliente(cedula, nombre, correo, fecha, direccion)
> VALUES('$cedula', '$nombre','$correo','$fecha','$direccion')" ;
> mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
> mysqli_close($conexion);
> }
> ?>
> ```

Y este es el codigo html con extensión .php solo tengo estos dos documentos y quiero que en el mismo html me salga la tabla de mi base de datos gracias.

> ```
> <html lang="en">
> <head>
>     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
>     <title>formulario de cliente</title>
> </head>
> <body>
> <form action="grabar.php" method="post">
>      <section class="form-register">       
>         <h4>Ingrese el cliente:</h4>
>         <h4>Cedula:<input class="controls" type="text" name="cedula"  placeholder="ingrese el numero de la cedula"></h4>
>         <h4>Nombre:<input class="controls" type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="ingrese el nombre"></h4>
>         <h4>Correo:<input class="controls" type="email" name="correo" placeholder="ingrese el correo"></h4>
>         <h4>Fecha de nacimiento:<input class="controls" type="date" name="fecha"  placeholder="ingrese la fecha de
> ```
>
> nacimiento">
>
> ##### Direccion:

Comment: Se me olvidó mencionar que mi base de datos se llama tienda y la tabla se llama cliente todo en minúscula, hecho con mysql.admin.

Comment: Debes agregar lo que has intentado para mostrar la tabla y los problemas que tienes al hacerlo.

Comment: No se como hacerlo por eso necesito saber como se hace

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Cuando dices mostrarlo en un documento a que te refieres ??? un word, un TXT una imagen????

Comment: – ArcanisGK507 ah? jaja wey no fui muy claro? como que en word jaja nooo, lo quiero en un doc.php con un th y tr que muestre mi base de datos

Comment: Tienes que ejecutar una consulta del tipo `SELECT` que obtenga todas las filas de tu tabla y luego leer fila por fila para mostrar los datos.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php En el manual de PHP tienes un par de ejemplos